# Redimensionar botones personalizados telegram bot python

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, telegram, telegram-bot

Estoy intentando redimensionar los botones del keyboard de telegram, pero no lo estoy logrando, ya probé de varias formas y no logro llegar a la solución. Estuve probando varios métodos y sin embargo no logro que funcione.

```
def Menu(update, context):
    bot = context.bot
    resize_keyboard=True
    ChatId = update.message.chat_id
    userName = update.effective_user["first_name"]
    logger.info(f'El Usuario {userName} Id:{ChatId} ah accedido al menu')
    keyboard = []
    keyboard.append([KeyboardButton(f'Informacion sobre el bot', callback_data='1')])
    keyboard.append([KeyboardButton(f'Mi WhatsApp', callback_data='2')])
    keyboard.append([KeyboardButton(f'Lista', callback_data='3')])
    keyboard.append([KeyboardButton(f'Bot para WA', callback_data='4')])
    keyboard.append([KeyboardButton(f'Redes Sociales', callback_data='5')])
    keyboard.append([KeyboardButton(f'Cafe?', callback_data='6')])
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    update.message.reply_text('*****Menu*****\nElige una de las siguientes opciones:',  reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Probe cosas como:

```
        keyboard.append([[KeyboardButton(f'choice1') ], [ KeyboardButton(f'choice2') ]])
```

Pero no funcionaron. Si alguien tiene alguna idea de como se puede implementar se agradece la ayuda, el bot es meramente para practicar y como hobby.

Esta es una idea de como quiero hacerlo para que se vea al usuario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final consegui solucionarlo colocando un array.

```
array =[
    keyboard.append([KeyboardButton(f'Informacion sobre el bot', callback_data='1'), KeyboardButton(f'Mi WhatsApp', callback_data='2')])
    ]
array = [
    keyboard.append([KeyboardButton(f'Lista', callback_data='3'), KeyboardButton(f'Bot para WA', callback_data='4')])
    ]
```

De esta manera pude lograr que quedara asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]